# Sorting a relationship in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a deck entity, with many cards belonging to that deck. The Cards entity has an attribute named `score` in which I want to sort a decks' cards by this score value. This is what I've tried:

```
    var cards = deck.cards?.allObjects as! [Cards]
    cards.sort(by: {$0.score > $1.score})
    deck.cards?.allObjects as! [Cards] = cards
```

but am getting this error `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '[Cards]'` since you cannot assign the relationship. Is there a way to sort this in real time or as a relationship rule in the data model?

edit: I know it can be done with a fetch request, but I am trying to avoid a fetch request since this operation will be have to be done pretty often

Comment: when you use a sort descriptor you are sorting in the database, you're not using quicksort. So your fetch will be performed after you have sorted you'r cards.

Comment: How would I perform a fetchRequest to get the exact deck I have passed through segue

Comment: Could you please give me more info? You want to sort objects in the database, and not when you get them. Your code is illegal because you don't own the objects the database owns them

Answer (score 1):

When you use a fetch request to get the decks, all the cards relationships within the deck are faulted objects. That means, when you access the cards through the decks, another access to the database is done.

This is expensive compared to one fetch request where you specify the deck and the order. Core Data (or better sqlite) is smart enough to cash the fetch request results is no change happened.

I would advise using fetch requests and try to fix the optimization problem when you face it.

You can fix the error you are getting by

```
let sortedCards = cards.sorted { $0.score > $1.score }
deck.cards = sortedCards
```

One more thing: To preserve the order of the cards in the database you need to use an NSOrderedSet

Comment: Yeah I eventually just had to use a fetch request with predicates and sort descriptors, I wanted to avoid it because the value I am sorting by changes for every element each time I would need to fetch